# Is there any basic string obfuscation I can use whilst pair programming?

Tags: c#, passwords, obfuscation

Whilst pair programming with database systems, sometimes we end up temporarily hardcoding credentials (typically of our own accounts), which leads to slight awkwardness with the partner trying to look away whenever the password is onscreen. Is there any simple way of using basic obfuscation (*ie*, rot13) to hardcode a password without other developers taking a quick look and seeing my password?

It doesn't need to be secure. It only needs to grease the social aspect. I don't want anything complex involving super secure encryption or reading passwords out of files etc. This has to be quick to implement (i.e. 10 seconds max) whilst coding on the fly. Ideally I want something like:

```
string password = string.rot13("zlcnffjbeq");
```

Does anything like this already exist?

Comment: A better solution is to set up a test user account, rather than using your own credentials to access the DB, etc.

Comment: Or simply use integrated security, where you map your user account to a database user account.

Comment: These solutions are both targeting a production solution for an implementation - not what I'm looking for. Our production code has much more complex security, what I'm interested in is something very fast to implement (takes 10 seconds max) to use during throwaway spike work to test component interactions. I don't want to be changing the contents of the database or troubleshooting windows accounts (especially when working cross-domain on VMs)

Comment: @MikeParker If the credentials are only used for a non-prod database then you shouldn't care if your partner sees them; there shouldn't be any real problem that he could cause with those credentials.  If those credentials are also used for prod systems, and your partner is not "fully trusted" in that you are potentially concerned with him using your credentials if he had it, then you should indeed tread this like a production environment.

Comment: If I didn't trust my pair programming partner I wouldnt be hardcoding passwords in front of him, and I'd need a much more rigorous method of hiding them. However, that's not to say we've agreed up front to share our passwords. It's not really a problem if he knows this password but it would feel more comfortable if it had at least some basic obfuscation as a token gesture.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store your password in a config file. For source control, use a dummy one. Then after getting latest version of the config file on your PC, you can modify the config by adding your password.

Answer (score 1):

***To configure SQL Server for Windows integrated security***

1. From the Windows Start menu, select Microsoft SQL Server, and then select Enterprise Manager.
2. Open the node for the server and expand the node for the database you want to give users permissions for.
3. Right-click the Users node and select New Database User.
4. In the Database User Properties dialog box, enter domain\username in the Login name box, and then click OK. Additionally, configure the SQL Server to allow all domain users to access the database.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Connection strings become `Server=x;Initial Catalog=y;Integrated Security=true` instead of `Server=x;Initial Catalog=y;User=you;Pwd=yourpassword`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [base64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) and just keep the base64 version of your password somewhere handy for cut and paste, bearing in mind that your system admin will have a blue fit if they find out about this.  Both the suggestions in comments (@Oli/@CodeCaster) are preferable to this, imo.

[DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741.aspx) is more work but arguably a balanced solution to your requirement, with some security.

> The .NET Framework provides access to the data protection API (DPAPI),
>   which allows you to encrypt data using information from the current
>   user account or computer. When you use the DPAPI, you alleviate the
>   difficult problem of explicitly generating and storing a cryptographic
>   key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store your password in a String variable like here

```
/* Variable that stores the password */                                             string pwd = "12345";

string password = string.rot13(pwd);
```

and tab it out of the visual range of the editor. This would be a proper solution to your problem.

Then you can use the string variable somewhere else in your code and no one can see your password unless he scrolls to the right

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, add lots of whitespace to the start of the line. Interesting idea :)